# Functional calculus for arbitrary $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, functional-calculus

Some of what I have read recently on using functional calculus for non-unital (or just arbitrary) $C^*$-algebras has left me puzzled and made me wonder if I have been harbouring a few misconceptions. I outline here my current (possibly incorrect) approach and am hoping to become more confident applying this and clear up any issues. My main source is $\S$ 2.2 of these [online notes](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Edana/bookspapers/cstar.pdf); a more detailed account of the functional calculus is given [here](https://math.ananas.nu/korn/015b.pdf). Apologies for the length.

If $A$ is a unital $C^*$-algebra and $a\in A$ is normal, then there exists a unique isometric $*$-isomorphism $\Psi:C(\sigma(a))\to C^*(\lbrace 1_A,a\rbrace)$ with $\Psi(\text{id})=a$, where $\text{id}:\sigma(a)\to\mathbb{C}$ is given by $\text{id}(\lambda):=\lambda$. This isomorphism is constructed using the Abstract Spectral Theorem and the $*$-isomorphism induced by the evaluation $h\mapsto h(a):\Delta\to\sigma(a)$. Uniqueness follows easily from the fact that the polynomials are dense in $C(\sigma(a))$.

Moving on to the general case, since $\tilde{A}$ is unital and $a$ is normal in $\tilde{A}$, we have a unique $*$-isomorphism $$\Psi:C(\sigma_A(a)\cup\lbrace0\rbrace)\to C^*(\lbrace1_{\tilde{A}},a\rbrace)$$ with $\Psi(\text{id})=a$, where $\text{id}$ is defined on $\sigma_A(a)\cup\lbrace0\rbrace$ this time. Defining $\mathcal{C}(a)$ to be the $C^*$-subalgebra of $C(\sigma_A(a))$ consisting of those $f$ for which there exists a (necessarily unique) continuous extension $\tilde{f}$ to $\sigma_A(a)\cup\lbrace0\rbrace$ with $\tilde{f}(0)=0$, $\Psi$ restricts to a $*$-isomorphism $$\mathcal{C}(a)\to C^*(\lbrace a\rbrace),$$ still mapping $\text{id}$ to $a$ of course but with the constant polynomials cut out (identify $\mathcal{C}(a)$ with those $f\in C(\sigma_A(a)\cup\lbrace0\rbrace)$ with $f(0)=0$) . If $0\notin\sigma_A(a)$, then it follows from the Pasting Lemma that $\mathcal{C}(a)=C(\sigma_A(a))$.

Would it then suffice to use this trimmed down version of the functional calculus unless constant terms are needed in the unital case e.g. $f(a)=1_A-a$?

Comment: Everything you say seems fine. What problems are you facing?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I haven't encountered any factual errors, but a couple of things have confused me. First of all is the reference to $C_0(\sigma(a)\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace)$ in some texts (how does this tie into my approach outlined above?) and secondly whether or not it is best to restrict to $\mathcal{C}(a)$ when $A$ is unital and $0\in\sigma(a)$. I'm trying to take the most holistic approach possible to this so I don't have to break into different cases unless strictly necessary.

Comment: The simple approach is that even to define the spectrum, you need to work on the unitization. So all functional calculus will usually be done in the unitization. If $A$ is not unital and you do functional calculus with $f$ such that $f(0)=0$, then you stay in $A$. The notation $C_0(\sigma(a)\setminus\{0\})$ is a convoluted way of saying $f\in C(\sigma(a))$, $f(0)=0$.